R programming - Error in calcCurveGrob(x, x$debug) : end points must not be identical
I am new to R programming and have been trying to plot places (airports) in a map. I am using RStudio (2024.04.2 Build 764) and R (4.4.1).
The datasets are getting populated properly as I can see from the Environment Data tab in RStudio.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(corrr)
flights <- read.csv("Flights.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
airports <- read.csv("Airports.csv")
flights <- merge(flights, airports, by.x="To", by.y="destin")
flights <- merge(flights, airports, by.x="From", by.y="airport")
worldmap <- borders("world", colour="#efede1", fill="#efede1") 

But in the actual map plotting using ggplot(), I am getting the error "Error in calcCurveGrob(x, x$debug) : end points must not be identical". The Plot window in RStudio is showing a white blank screen.
Below is the ggplot code:
ggplot() + worldmap + 
    geom_curve(data=flights, aes(x = lon.x, y = lat.x, xend = lon.y, yend = lat.y), col = "#b29e7d", size = 1, curvature = .2) + 
    geom_point(data=airports, aes(x = lon, y = lat), col = "#970027") + 
    geom_text_repel(data=airports, aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = airport), col = "black", size = 2, segment.color = NA) + 
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"), 
          axis.line = element_blank(),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          axis.text.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks = element_blank(),
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          axis.title.y = element_blank()
    )

Any help from this forum will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Check that you don't have a row in flights where the destination's lat/lon is the same as the origin with
flights[flights$lat.x == flights$lat.y | flights$lon.x == flights$lon.y , ]  

for example: this code fails with
Error in calcCurveGrob(x, x$debug) : end points must not be identical 

because the last flight is from LAX to LAX:
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)

flights <- data.frame(From = c("JFK", "LAX", "LAX"), 
                      To = c("LAX", "JFK", "LAX"))

airports <- data.frame(
  airport = c("JFK", "LAX"), 
  lat = c(40.639751, 33.942536), 
  lon = c(-73.778925, -118.408071))

flights <- merge(flights, airports, by.x="To", by.y="airport")
flights <- merge(flights, airports, by.x="From", by.y="airport")

# check that the endpoints are not identical
flights[flights$lat.x == flights$lat.y | flights$lon.x == flights$lon.y , ]  

worldmap <- borders("world", colour="#efede1", fill="#efede1") 

ggplot() + 
  worldmap + 
  geom_curve(
    data=flights, 
    aes(x = lon.x, y = lat.x, xend = lon.y, yend = lat.y), 
    col = "#b29e7d", linewidth = 1, curvature = .2) + 
  geom_point(
    data=airports, 
    aes(x = lon, y = lat), col = "#970027") + 
  geom_text_repel(
    data=airports, 
    aes(x = lon, y = lat, label = airport), 
    col = "black", size = 2, segment.color = NA) + 
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"), 
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  )


Hi Michiel, Appreciate the quick response. I did find 1 row where the lat and lon were the same in the flights dataset. But, even after I corrected it, I am still getting the same error. Is there anything else I should be looking into?

Update: I found another instance, this time in the code (I was using a wrong dataset in the merge function). It is working now. Thanks a lot for your help.
